# Cómo averiguar con VBA de Access qué codificación tiene (ANSI, UTF-8, UCS-2, etc...) un archivo de texto

Tags: vba, archivo, ms-access

Se trata de que quiero incorporar, con VBA, a una tabla de MySQL, las líneas de un fichero ascii elegido de entre los existentes en una carpeta (donde residen varios archivos descargados de distintas fuentes: UNIX, Windows,...). Para poder leer las líneas perfectamente y asegurarme de su correcta incorporación a la tabla donde cargarlo, quiero comprobar ( es el motivo de mi consulta), que la codificación de dicho archivo origen tienen la codificación que necesito (en este caso es la UTF-8 sin BOM) para que, si no es, se informe al usuario de que la codificación del archivo es incorrecta

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Vale, lo siento.

Comment: Se trata de que quiero incorporar, con VBA, a una tabla de MySQL, las líneas de un fichero ascii elegido de entre los existentes en una carpeta (donde residen varios archivos descargados de distintas fuentes: UNIX, Windows,...). 
Para poder leer las líneas perfectamente y asegurarme de su correcta incorporación a la tabla donde cargarlo, quiero comprobar ( 
es el motivo de mi consulta), que la codificación de dicho archivo origen tienen la codificación que necesito 
(en este caso es la UTF-8 sin BOM) para que, si no es, se informe al usuario de que la codificación del archivo es incorrecta.

Comment: Después ya realizo otro tipo de comprobaciones antes de la carga, como que la estructura de columnas es la correcta, pero este tema ya lo tengo solucionado